# Is it possible to have iOS Project base on Client Provisioning Profile?

Tags: ios, push-notification

I am using xCode 6 and working well with my Developer Account (not client Developer Account). The project I am building for Client is ready to UAT and since it need to test Push Notification function.

Since they have their own Push Notification Server and their own PEM cert. How should I change my project/Provisioning Profile to accept Push Message from their server?

THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If client have own PEM cert then you have to use client developer account for download your provisioning profile.
Your must check that your client provisioning profile connected to push notification certificate.